# Help finding a contradiction - Graph Theory $\Rightarrow$ RESOLVED

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

Here is the question I am trying to prove by contradiction as my professor recommended but in attempting to prove I cannot find a contradiction. Can someone point me in the right direction of what I am not considering? Thank you.

Let $G$ be a graph of order $n$. Prove that is the minimum degree $\delta(G)\ge\frac{n-1}{2}$ then $G$ is connected.

My proof: Let $G$ be a graph of order $n$. Assume, to the contrary that G is disconnected. Then $G$ has at least two components. Now assume, without loss of generality, that there are just two components $G_1$ and $G_2$. Let $n_1$ and $n_2$ be the order of $G_1$ and $G_2$ respectively. Then $n_1 \le n_2$ and $n_1 \le \frac{n}{2}$. Every vertex of $G_1$ has degree at most $n_1 - 1 \le \frac{n}{2}-1=\frac{n-2}{2}$ thus $\delta(G_1)\le \frac{n-2}{2}\le\frac{n}{2}$. It then follows that $\delta(G)\le\delta(G_1)\le\frac{n-2}{2}\le\frac{n}{2}$. (Here is where I have trouble proceeding, I am missing the contradiction.)

Comment: Your lower bound on the minimum degree cannot be right - if $n\ge4$ is it bigger than $n-1$. (Although I think this playing no role in your difficulties.)

Comment: Hint: you haven't used $G_2$ yet.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I considered $G_2$, however, I couldn't quite see how showing that $\delta(G)\le\delta(G_1)\le\frac{n-2}{2}\le\delta(G_2)\le\frac{n}{2}$ helped the issue. Could you explain further?

Comment: The inequality $\delta(G)\le\frac{n-2}2\lt\frac{n-1}2$ contradicts the assumption $\delta(G)\ge\frac{n-1}2$

Comment: @bof I see how that statement is true yet isn't $\delta(G)\ge\frac{n-1}{2}$ the assumption if G is connected. I led with assuming G is disconnected so I didn't think I could use the definition of G is connected.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Since $G_1$ and $G_2$ are components of $G$ then I thought that if I can show $\delta(G_1)$ (or $\delta(G_2)$) then $\delta(G)$ could only be at most $\delta(G_1)$.

Comment: @Methmatics Huh? You lost me somewhere. You want to prove that ***IF*** $\delta(G)\ge\frac{n-1}2$ ***THEN*** $G$ is connected. So you ***ASSUME*** that $\delta(G)\ge\frac{n-1}2$ holds, and using that you try to prove. that $G$ is connected. Trying for a proof by contradiction, you assume that $G$ is not connected. So you need to derive a contradiction from the assumptions that (a) $\delta(G)\ge\frac{n-1}2$ and (b) $G$ is not connected. But (as you noticed) (b) implies $\delta(G)\lt\frac{n-1}2$ which contradicts (a), Q.E.D. What am I missing?

Comment: @bof Oh! I see. This makes a lot of sense. You are right I set up the assumption missing a critical component. I will fix it.

Comment: By the way, $\delta(G)\ge\frac{n-1}2$ is not "the definition of $G$ is connected". The path $P_{5}$ is connected but $\delta(P_5)=1.$ The definition of "$G$ is connected" is "every pair of vertices is connected by a path".